# Set StartUp Project parameter for Entity Framework migrations

Tags: entity-framework, migration

When using EF 4.3.1 migrations every time i need to add a migration or update database i have to use the StartUpProject parameter. Can I set this somewhere so I don't have to keep doing this? I don't want to set my data project as the start up project. My context and migrations are in different projects if that makes a difference.

Exception thrown when not using StartpProject parameter:

```
update-database -verbose
Using NuGet project 'Data.Deployment'.
Using StartUp project ''.
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ArgumentException: The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeDispMethod(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Object target, Object[] args, Boolean[] byrefModifiers, Int32 culture, String[] namedParameters)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at System.Management.Automation.ComMethod.InvokeMethod(PSMethod method, Object[] arguments)
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

Answer (score 12):

At least with Entity Framework 6, to specify the Startup Project use the `-StartUpProjectName` parameter with update-database:

```
update-database -StartUpProjectName <String>
```

You can use the `get-help` command within Package Manager Console to view possible parameters for commands:

```
get-help update-database -detailed
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the StartupProject parameter: `Update-database -StartupProject "PROJECTNAME"`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what you're talking about, but you can set the default project in the Package Manager Console to the project where your Migrations config resides in; it's the rightmost dropdown list.
This way I've never had to provide the startup project as an argument.

Comment: I have done that, but if I don't specify the StartupProject parameter it throws an exception

Comment: Seriously? Can you post the entire output of the exception?

Comment: added in the exception in the original post above

Comment: Hm, I didn't realise this until now, but apparently the StartUp project is your solution startup project; the default project is used to look for the Migrations scaffolding code. Is it acceptable for you to put your Migrations code in your current startup project? It's not exactly clean, but the only way I can see...

Comment: Nope, I guess it's possible, just would really like to avoid that as much as possible. Is there anywhere I can set this in a config file or app.config? is it because it can't find the connection string for the db? When I pass in the startupproject parameter I pass in the data project name which is where the migrations are, not the actual solution startup project if that makes sense?

Comment: No, I'm starting to think MS just designed it this way. Behind the scenes you're calling migrate.exe with some parameters. Any exe can have its own config file, but it's very difficult to call the config file from an unrelated project (your project in this case). So you're left with using commandline arguments, and apparently MS defaults to your startup project when you don't explicitly provide one... Since you're passing your data project explicitly, it works, but if you don't, it will search your startup (web?) project, finding nothing and handing you that nasty reflection error...

Answer (score 1):

A clean way around this is to attach a Test Project to the solution.

Even if you don't want to write lots of unit tests, it's an appropriate start-up project for a data layer namespace or similar.

That makes your start up issue cleaner, the package manager applies to the whole solution IIRC - so make sure the default project is the one with the migrations folder in it.